# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

Tags: java, hibernate

This is the query where I am getting error In Out something;

```
 SELECT BUS_EVT_LOG_ID,MAINT_OBJ_CD,BUS_OBJ_CD,PK_VALUE1,PK_VALUE2,PK_VALUE3,PK_VALUE4,PK_VALUE5,LOG_DTTM,VERSION,MESSAGE_CAT_NBR,MESSAGE_NBR,USER_ID,LOG_DETAIL FROM cisadm.F1_BUS_EVT_LOG where trim(BUS_OBJ_CD) in ('CM-InvoiceDetails', 'CM-InvoiceSummary') and PK_VALUE5 != 'Y' and LOG_DTTM &gt; TO_DATE('#{jobParameters[edbtimestamp]}' ,'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

Error I don't know what is causing the issue sql query or something else

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28374: typed master key not found in wallet' ,'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss')]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17041]; Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.translateSqlException(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:230) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader.openCursor(JdbcCursorItemReader.java:133) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:453) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2086) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3772) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3822) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader.openCursor(JdbcCursorItemReader.java:128) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:453) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Spring SpEL integration doesn't work properly. My guess is that `#{jobParameters[edbtimestamp]}` will inject some parameter markers i.e. `:param1` or `?` to the SQL but `JdbcCursorItemReader` is not setting a value for that parameter.